# C# vs. JAVA - What benefit is there to interpreting Java bytecode vs JITing?

Tags: java, c#, cil

I was reading this [comparison](http://www.25hoursaday.com/csharpvsjava.html) between JAVA and C# and was wondering about this statement:

> NOTE: While the Java platform supports interpretation of byte code or
>   byte code being JITed then run natively, the .NET platform only
>   supports native execution of C# code because the IL code is always
>   natively compiled before running.

<strike>Was this purely a marketing play on the part of Microsoft to make is hard to deploy C# to OS's other than Windows or</strike> Does it provide some benefit such as performance or security?

Comment: C# is not difficult to deploy to other OS's (its not C# thats deployed, but the MSIL output of the compiler), and is easily run with mono on other OS's. This really isn't about marketing, but performance, the closer you are to the "metal", the faster the program runs. The MSIL isn't JIT'ed until runtime anyway, so it has to run through the interpreter at least once before its JIT'ed to native.

Comment: The question is backwards. You say "Java has a feature, .NET does not, what is the compelling benefit to .NET *not having that feature*?"  That's an impossible question to answer; the lack of a feature does not confer a benefit, rather, it saves a cost. The better question is "what was so compelling about that feature that the Java team decided to spend time and effort implementing it?"

Comment: To reinforce what @RonBeyer said, the important point in the quote is _"the .NET platform only supports native execution of C# code because the IL code is always natively compiled"_. C# (as a language) is independent of that limitation.

Comment: @Charlie As an aside, were you aware that's a 14 year-old comparison?

Comment: Are you asking why C# supports only JIT-compilation when Java also supports interpretation, or are you asking why C# bothers with JIT-compilation at all, when it could go for AOT-compilation instead?

Comment: @EricLippert You are right - I was actually confused about whether the ability to interpret without JITing was a feature or a liability. I now think that it's a feature, but likely hard to take advantage of and probably doesn't even make much difference in most cases.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I am curious about why there's a shift now from JIT to AOT, but no that's not was I was originally asking.

Comment: @RonBeyer I agree and misspoke. I was originally confused about whether native compilation referred to the stuff that's included in an EXE apart from the MSIL that is platform specific. My understanding is that Java handles that differently, but the above comments helped me understand that as unrelated to this concept of interpreting without JITing.

Comment: @Mikaveli I would be interested in a more recent comparison of Java and C# if you know of one.

Comment: This is not true. The micro framework (.Net MF) use an interpreter. At least on my gadgeteer devices

Comment: @adrianm I would say .NET MF is an outlier when speaking about this topic, its a specialized version of .NET designed to run on MCU's. Any type of Javascript system for MCU's would have the same issue. I'd ignore outlier implementations for these types of discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the **just in time** approach the byte code is translated into native code at the time of the first execution. Compiling just before execution require more time, so the first time a method is executed it's slower than the second time.
.Net compiles the entire program only one time. So during the first time the execution phase is shorted because there is no lag due to compilation.
The difference is only in the first time the code is executed, so the more times the code is executed more and more the two approaches become similar in terms of speed.

Comment: It also seems there is a lag the first time for .NET when it has to compile which is the whole point of AOT so I don't think that part of your answer is correct.

Comment: Your answer also helped me discover that it is possible for a JVM like Hotspot to enable the code to start faster to first time it is run by using the interpreter, which will run slower over time, but then it can switch over the optimized compiled code when it's run again see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907968/difference-between-a-jvm-with-and-without-jit